# SharePoint workflow task approval takes too long to respond

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, tasks

I installed Workflow Manager and deployed a simple workflow to test it out. Basically what it does is assign a task and then once the workflow is approved it writes some words to history.

**Now here's the problem:** the workflow runs flawlessly UNTIL it reaches a task. After I approve the task, the workflow is stuck there for a whole day before it continues running. This is just an absurd behavior.

What might be the cause of this?

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot of the workflow, there may be a step holding it up.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/9PfPt Here is my Workflow. There is no step in between.

Comment: Within "configure" are you assigning it to a specific person or waiting for the system to find that person?

Comment: I assign it to 1 specific person.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a timer job dependency schedule to run once in a day which is why it is taking too long (perhaps a day) to continue with the flow after task is being approved.